# Cloud Endpoints Frameworks v1 is deprecated as of August 2, 2017

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have migrated my python application to endpoints framework 2 using this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python). I have used API class for migrating. Even after the migration google sending  '[Reminder] Cloud Endpoints Frameworks v1 is deprecated as of August 2, 2017' the reminder mail? Is this an issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had the same thing. Completely moved to v2 but still got the mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email is sent out based on if an app has received v1 traffic in the past week or so. If you migrated a long time ago, then this is a bug, please let me know. Otherwise, it is expected.